# How to read a scanf for multiple integer and string inputs until EOF?

Tags: c

I need to do scanf function like that: scanf("%s%d%d%s%d%d%s%d%d", X, &LO, &HI, Y, &LO2, &HI2, Z, &LO3, &HI3) and I want whenever user hit ctrl+D to end the scanning and turn off the program.

For example:

```
l 7 9 c 3 8 v 4 ctrl+D //input

--> end of scanning and the end of program.
```

Could you please help me to do that? I am a total beginner in programming..

Comment: Always check `scanf`'s return value. If you ask for 9 inputs and `scanf` returns anything other than 9, this means that something went wrong, and you didn't receive 9 inputs.  (And, specifically, if it returns `EOF`, this probably means the user typed control-D before inputting anything.)

Answer (score -1):

For a Unix type terminal, Ctrl-D is usually the termios VEOF character, and is not passed through to standard input when the terminal is in canonical input mode. In that case, typing the Ctrl-D character at the beginning of a line will make `scanf` see an end-of-file condition, but it needs to be at the beginning of a line, not partway through a line as in your example. So you may need to type a Carriage Return before the Ctrl-D in order to return from `scanf` early.

You can check the return value of `scanf` to see if it read the required number of input values, and end the program if the return value is incorrect.